# sudo command on MacOS Sierra does not respect timestamp_timeout

Tags: shell, sudo, macos-sierra

After upgrading to MacOS Sierra (10.12), my `sudo` command seems to be acting differently. See the following test case:

```
# Run in terminal pane #1: (should prompt for password)
sudo -v

# Run in terminal pane #2: (should NOT prompt for password)
sudo -v
```

The above works as expected on earlier versions of OS X. However, on Sierra, the second command prompts for the password again. It does not prompt for the password within the same terminal pane. This seems to only happen for the `root` user; the following works as expected on all OS versions including Sierra:

```
# Run in terminal pane #1: (prompts for password)
sudo -v -u "$USER"

# Run in terminal pane #2: (does not prompt for password)
sudo -v -u "$USER"
```

Looking at `/ect/sudoers`, the `timestamp_timeout` value is not set to `0`. I've briefly looked over the [changelog for 1.7 to 1.8](https://www.sudo.ws/stable.html#1.8.17p1) but could not come up with anything significant other than there being a mention of a policy plugin for Sierra when running `sudo -V`.

Can anybody help me figure out what has changed? I have a script that relies on the `sudo` timeout value for a keepalive and on Sierra it is prompting for the password constantly since it seems to no longer use a timestamp for the `root` user.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a ton of searching and comparing the `sudo` configuration on older OS versions to Sierra's (`sudo su; sudo -V`), it seems that Sierra enables `tty_tickets` by default now, causing the issues mentioned above. As far as I can tell, this was an undocumented change. To fix, the following needs to be added to the `/etc/sudoers` file via running `sudo visudo`,

```
Defaults !tty_tickets
```

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; BAD IDEA. This old behavior, while an option to sudo, is used as a default by NO OTHER UNIX-y OS that I have ever encountered. The reason being that it's trivial to exploit, and when exploited, the malignant code doing so will have full control of your system.

### Original very long rant-y post, correctly pointed out to be blahdiblah:

LOL, this is funny. I came here from googling because I couldn't remember how I would change the old behavior to this new, correct one (used by every other UNIX-y OS out there). Hadn't even noticed my new Sierra Mac now behaved properly.

I wrote on the Mac forums earlier about this previous behavior which is a gaping security hole. I even supplied a three-line proof-of-concept script that would simply sit around (as a regular user) waiting for a `sudo` event to appear **anywhere**, then instantly gain root access to the system. I was booed out of the thread by the fanboys, then got banned from it from calling out lies. Seems Apple were listening, though. Good job, for once, Cupertino. Bad, BAD idea to try to get the old behavior back.

For reference, here's the three-liner. It doesn't do anything malignant, just adds a dummy file to the root of the filesystem once gaining sudo. Run it in a script (or just paste it somewhere which doesn't already have sudo), then either do a sudo in another terminal app/window or app which uses sudo (e.g. TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt or similar), then watch it work.

```
tail -f -n 0 /var/log/system.log | grep -m 1 -E 'sudo\[[0-9]+\]:\s+'$USER
echo "Gonna play around with root privs ..."
sudo touch /kilroy-was-here
```

Comment: Nice story, but actually, SO is not a "story telling place"; at least in my eyes. You see, answers should be meant to *help* people solving problems. But within your "answer", I would say 75% of that text do not add value at all. So, my personal recommendation (esp. when you are interested in gaining reputation for your answers): avoid the story telling. Clear precise facts tend to attract more positive feedback than answers starting with LOL. But as said, those were my personal 2 cent.

Comment: You know, @GhostCat, that's a perfectly valid point, and I totally agree. +1 on that comment from me. This was 6:30 in the morning, trying to leave the Sandman for work. That said, I'm just gonna add a quick TLDR at the top, because... Not sure... Don't really care about Apple's bugs anymore :D Also having a beer and playing Clash of Clans, so there's that :D